# how to map the data in table row?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I fetch channels 1,2,3,4 from get method and then call post data in which I call function parameter and check the get method data in the body parameter of post method and print the data of post method but it is in the form of object in the console and I want to store in temp and them display it in the web page.

**code***

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./main.css"
import { AiOutlineCheck, AiOutlineClose, AiOutlineArrowUp, AiOutlineArrowDown } from "react-icons/ai";
import axios from "axios";


const Header = () => {
  const [setdata, fetchdata] = useState([]);
  const [setpostData, Postdata] = useState([]);



  useEffect(() => {
    getfetchData();
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    setdata.forEach(function (val) {
      getPostData(val.Player, val.IP, val.Port, val.ChannelName);
      // setInterval(() => {
      //   getPostData(val.Player, val.IP, val.Port, val.ChannelName);
      // }, 500);
    });
  }, [setdata]);

  function getfetchData() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:9763/api/getPlayers",
      {
        headers: {
          "accepts": "application/json",
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
        auth: {
          username: 'admin',
          password: 'password'
        },

      }).then(response => {
        //console.log(response.data)
        //console.log([...Object.values(response.data).flat()]);
        fetchdata([...Object.values(response.data).flat()]);
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }


  var temp = [];
  // Post Data   

  function getPostData(Player, IP, Port, channelName) {
    var data = {
      PlayerName: Player,
      ChannelName: channelName,
      Port: Port,
      IpAddress: IP
    }
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://localhost:9763/api/getPlayerStatus',
      data,
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      auth: {
        username: 'admin',
        password: 'password'
      }
    }).then(response => {
     
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log("Error In Post Data", error);
    });
  }
 // console.log("set", setpostData);


  return (

    <div className="container-fluid pt-2">
      <table className=" table-borderless text-center" id="refresh">
        <thead>
          <tr className="title" >
            {
              Object.values(setdata).map((val) => {
                return (
                  <th key={val.Player} > <AiOutlineCheck style={{ color: 'black', backgroundColor: "#41fc00", borderRadius: "25px" }} />
                    {val.ChannelName} </th>
                )
              })
            }
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr >
            {
              setpostData.map((val, index) => {
                //  console.log("Inside Map", val);
                return (
                  <td key={index}>{val.Properties.Upcounter} </td>
                )
              })
            }
          </tr>
          <tr>
            {
              setpostData.map((val, index) => {
                //  console.log("Inside Map", val);
                return (
                  <td key={index}>{val.Properties.DownCounter} </td>
                )
              })
            }

          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    
    </div >

  );
}
export default Header;
```

**Console Response.data  show object**
[image: Console Response.data show object]

how to make this 4 object in one array so that its easily to map in row

```
      [
            {
                "Status": 1000,
                "Properties": {
                    "ClipName": "Clip1",
                    "Upcounter": "15:33:44:33",
                    "DownCounter": "16:33:44:33",
                    "ChannelName": "Channel1",
                    "StartTimeCode": "00:00:00:00",
                    "PlayerName": "Vtr1",
                    "Duration": "12:00:00:01"
                }
            }
        ]
        [
            {
                "Status": 1000,
                "Properties": {
                    "ClipName": "Clip3",
                    "Upcounter": "12:33:44:33",
                    "DownCounter": "12:33:44:33",
                    "ChannelName": "Channel3",
                    "StartTimeCode": "00:00:00:00",
                    "PlayerName": "Vtr3",
                    "Duration": "12:00:00:01"
                }
            }
        ]
[
            {
                "Status": 1000,
                "Properties": {
                    "ClipName": "Clip1",
                    "Upcounter": "15:33:44:33",
                    "DownCounter": "16:33:44:33",
                    "ChannelName": "Channel1",
                    "StartTimeCode": "00:00:00:00",
                    "PlayerName": "Vtr1",
                    "Duration": "12:00:00:01"
                }
            }
        ]
[
            {
                "Status": 1000,
                "Properties": {
                    "ClipName": "Clip1",
                    "Upcounter": "15:33:44:33",
                    "DownCounter": "16:33:44:33",
                    "ChannelName": "Channel1",
                    "StartTimeCode": "00:00:00:00",
                    "PlayerName": "Vtr1",
                    "Duration": "12:00:00:01"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to map the values before `<tr>` I think its work. can you post the output UI of the table

And for merging array object you can do this way. I think its work

```
var newArray = [...arr1, ...arr2, ...aar3,...arr4];
```

Comment: i use map but it's  show only  one data in table row but i have 4 value and when i refresh  page value change to 2 response.data

Comment: why are using two states in the table

Comment: 2 api first for table header (getFetchdata) and second for table row(getPostData)

Comment: you can merge it into one array that means table head and table row values

Comment: i update the question is this possible to make 4 different object   inside the 1 array  (push)

Comment: yeah its possible but where you will get this 4 objects. Plz check my updated answer